# Do I qualify for visa free layover in China?

Tags: visas, usa, china, layovers, air-china

I am traveling from US to India, stopping in PEK.

I hold Indian passport, but my US visa has expired (traveling to get it renewed).

I was wondering if I can take the US -> PEK -> India flight without holding any Chinese visa?

Basically does the fact that I do not have valid US visa, invalidate the layover requirements for China.

Comment: Technically you wont have a valid visa for the USA as far as the Chinese authorities will know.

Comment: But I am headed to India, so why does US visa matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Timatic it seems like you qualify for transit without visa if your transit time is less than 24 hours:

> Transit - China (People's Rep.) (CN)
>
> Visa: Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of confirmed onward air, cruise
> or train tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours. Transit incl.
> multiple stops within China (People's Rep.), with a total transit time
> of max. 24 hours, is permitted. They must travel to a third country.
>
> Transit without visa (TWOV) is not possible at Fuzhou (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX) and Yanji (YNJ).
>
> This does not apply at Urumqi (URC).
>
> This does not apply at Guangzhou (CAN).
>
> All transiting passengers are subject to a check by immigration.
> Passengers in transit must hold passports or other documents accepted
> to enter China (People's Rep.). .

Comment: So looks like the fact that my US visa has expired won't be an issue.
(I am in US legally though visa has expired).